# Flow not displaying onedrive for business files

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to create a flow that links files on my company's onedrive for business account with our SharePoint site. The first time I tried this, when I clicked the bar beside "*Folder", it listed the folders on my onedrive account and I was able to select the one wanted to create the flow between.

View Creating Flow:
[image: View Creating Flow]

However. A week later, I resolved an unrelated issue with the process and tried to create a new flow, but now, when I try to click the bar, this is all I get. Root is not a file on my onedrive, and it doesn't expand into anything. I have tried, putting in, "/File Name", but it won't recognize the file name, and the flow fails when I test it. I am not sure what I am doing differently this time that is causing Flow not to recognize the onedrive folders.

There is no folder, "root" in my one drive, and root doesn't expand into anything:
[image: There is no folder, "root" in my one drive, and root doesn't expand into anything]

Answer (score 0):

Root means the primary (main) OneDrive folder.  If you click on the > next to root, it will open up the primary OneDrive folder and list all of the subfolders, as well as, all of the documents in the root folder.